# SSL Websites not working with VPN

Tags: vpn, ssl

I run a VPN service, and have just realized that websites that use SSL never load.
A little confused by this, since nothing is blocking the SSL.

However, I had a thought that I would need my own SSL certificate for the VPN domain for SSL sites to work through the VPN.

Am I correct, or is something else probably wrong with my setup?

***Edit:***
Through further testing, I've found that I can use ALL of Google's SSL-secured sites perfectly fine.
The VPS server machines are all using Google's DNS servers for their DNS (8.8.8.8); perhaps it's something to do with this setup?

Oh, and it seems to be blocking advertising on Superuser also.

Comment: I run several OpenVPN servers, and through each of them I can connect to sites using SSL without any problem.

Comment: @MariusMatutiae I just updated the question with more info, maybe it'll help.

Comment: I would like to confirm the following details:

1.Which type of VPN are you using, please tell more about your VPN on both server and client side?
2.Can you ping the problematic websites via VPN?
3.Which browser are you using?
4.What if use another browser to access this websites via VPN?

Comment: VPN is PPTP, using Linux's PPTPD, I can ping all websites, even the problematic ones, just not the https://. All browsers have this error. I connected my Windows Server DC to the VPN, and that had problems also, same as my iPhone.

Comment: Yes, very odd that Google sites work but may I know some of those problematic websites? their certificates may be revoked and you system may have settings for certificate values and dates.

Comment: freelancer.com, facebook.com, Stack Exchange site logins, pretty much any site with a https connection, except Google stuff.

Comment: Did you figure out what was wrong? If yes, could you update by answering your question? @cybermonkey